# Tips or tools for debugging Spring applications?

Tags: java, spring, debugging

I am trying to use Spring for the first time in an application. The general issue that comes up repeatedly is how to debug Spring. The framework is configuration heavy so traditional code debugging seems fruitless. I have no real idea how to go about troubleshooting short of turning on the debugging level logs (which are lacking) and scanning through.

Are there any general tips or tools to assist Spring debugging?

Comment: If anyone is interested in helping with the specific issue I am having, I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888581/fixing-null-entitymanger-in-spring-mvc-application. This question is more about helping me figure out stuff in the future, teaching me to fish as it were.

Comment: see my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Eclipse, then get hold of the Spring IDE (available from the Eclipse Marketplace within the Help menu of Eclipse). This will provide code-completion, bean visualisation, and hot-linking to your config files.

Comment: I don't know whether the license was changed since this answer was first provided, however the SpringSource Tool Suite license allows free usage only for "non-production purposes of Licensee's internal business operations, development, evaluation, and education".

Comment: I just looked at one of the original posts from Spring from May 2009, which announced that STS would be free for *all* development purposes. So, I don't know how the development and production phases differ in their minds.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Spring debugging should be any different to any other debugging scenario.

What aspects of Spring are you using ? If you're using dependency injection properly, then I wouldn't anticipate any problems.

However if you're dynamically resolving beans via their name (at runtime, using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`) then I can see that's going to cause you problems anticipating flow of control etc., and would suggest that you revisit your IoC.

EDIT: It's quite useful to have the Spring source code available. It's well put together and quite readable, and therefore possibly of use when debugging.

Comment: I am using spring MVC with dependency injection. Using it "properly" is the problem. How do you about debugging dependency injection?

Comment: I would a) use constructor dependency injections b) instantiate your framework and then inspect what you've injected into your bean constructors. You're debugging the program in a static sense - i.e. how has it been constructed ?

Answer (score 0):

I generally just use the java debugger in eclipse - it works fine on most classes. Some classes are wrapped at compile/runtime by bytecode changes - for these you generally cannot put breakpoints in methods, however you can set a breakpoint at method entry.

If you have a very specific situation you maybe should elaborate a bit in your question.

I'm generally also ok with the logging levels - what do you think is wrong with them?

Comment: Well I was trying to keep this generic, but for latest issue I am trying to debug a null entity manager. The logging doesn't give me any useful information, or at least not anything that sticks out at me and you can't really set breakpoints on annotations.

Comment: The hint that you cannot put breakpoints into method bodies of some methods (in my case entry methods of a controller), but you can put a breakpoint at the method entry instead was really useful. (It was driving me nuts that debugging seemed to work at some places but not in others while debugging in NetBeans).

Answer (score 0):

As of 09/2011 (Version: 2.6.1.RELEASE, Build Id: 201105041000) a real annoyance is the fact that the debugger doesn't stop inside closures, so you have to remember to put a breakpoint inside the ones you want to examine; that is fine as it is "almost" going to a different class which a lot of time doens't matter, but when it does, you have to remember that.