# EntityManager null pointer exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to query a result from DB.
Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.java.utils.WebAppInfo.getAppName(WebAppInfo.java:14)
    at main.java.views.adminView.IndexView.loadPageInfo(IndexView.java:21)
    at main.java.controller.MainAction.welcome(MainAction.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Here's the function where that error is coming from.

```
@Resource(name="applicationInfoService")
    private static ApplicationInfoService applicationInfoService;

    public static ApplicationInfo getAppName() {
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = applicationInfoService.getAppNameResult(); 
        return applicationInfo;
    }
```

If i initiate application info service ( = new ApplicationInfoService()) I get a null pointer error to my Service class where query is made

```
@Service("applicationInfoService")
@Transactional
public class ApplicationInfoService {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager){ 
        this.entityManager = entityManager; 
    }

    public ApplicationInfo getAppNameResult() {
        String sql = "FROM ApplicationInfo";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        return (ApplicationInfo) query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Error goes to createQuery line and if i print out EntityManager it returns "null".
Why wont my Entitymanager get initialized. I am using allmost the same build up in my login system and it works over there. When i use multiple EntityManager classes in a project, do i need to configure them somehow? I am not sure how to fix this problem, since im new to spring, hibernate, JPA etc.

Comment: It's because it's static. Can you show the whole class containing the `getAppName()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Spring does not allow to inject `static` fields, thats why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

I can suggest you an work-arrond. Add the bellow block of code in your `WebAppInfo` class:

```
@Resource(name="applicationInfoService")
public void setService(ApplicationInfoService service) {
    WebAppInfo.applicationInfoService = service;
}
```

Don't forget remove `@Resouce` annotation from `applicationInfoService`.

**Edit:**

The above suggestion was only to fix the `NullPointerException` in your `WebAppInfo` class for the reason of not being initialized an `static` field!

But there are can be number of causes for your `EntityManager` being `null`. As you are saying it worked for you in other system. I suggest you to

- recheck the path of your `persistence.xml`, after the deployment.
- See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888581/fixing-null-entitymanger-in-spring-mvc-application).

And if these does not help you, please provide sufficient information of the exception trace and related code.

Comment: That did not help. I get null pointer even if I remove all static modifiers around that entity manager

Comment: @user1272486, I just edited my answer see this, if these does not help, please post your Exception trace with related code and configuration.

Comment: I read that topic but his solution didn't help mine. check here : https://github.com/Kapaacius/Fishfood Probably easier if you can see xml's also

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of injecting a value into a static field? It can only have one value per class loader and it sort of defeats the purpose of the IoC environment. Even though sazzadur's answer will get you past the `NullPointerException` its not going to save you from strange bugs if other classes do same thing.

Instead of mixing paradigms, I would consider dispatching with the `WebAppInfo` class, converting `ApplicationInfoService` to a singleton and injecting it wherever appropriate.

Comment: I changed my service to Singleton, but I am still getting null pointer. Now it keeps popping up to this line in Service class "Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);"